# Focus lost when selecting a choice in jQuery autocompletion dropdown list

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) for a text input. When selecting an item in the dropdown list of the autocompletion choices, I loose the focus on my text input.

Can I avoid that?
Is the dropdown list an element? Can I get its ID or select it in some way?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide some code snipit

Answer (score 3):

Add `focus` on `change`:

```
$('#myinput').change(function(){   
    $(this).focus(); 
});
```